# Git force or fake a commit reject

Tags: git

My work team has taken over responsibility for managing a number of git repositories containing mostly Perl scripts and some configuration files. Many of these scripts do not change much over time, but when they do, they often go through several iterations over the course of 2-3 weeks.

I've been tasked with providing some guidance when it comes to using git to manage these repos. I wanted to create some examples to show how to handle certain problems that might occur, like commits being rejected.

However, I'm having a hard time forcing any of the most common git errors - I guess git just works really well for this type of repo.

I'm looking for examples that are sure to have a commit get rejected, or will cause other commonly seen git errors, that is applicable to a repo of Perl scripts of 100-300 lines long

Comment: AFAIK Git will never refuse to commit something. If you mean failing to push to a remote, a common case is trying to push a diverged local branch.

Comment: Maybe you can be more specific about what you mean by "commits being rejected", and what "common git errors" you're thinking of - as others have said, git doesn't generally refuse to _commit_ anything. Are you thinking of "merge conflicts", where two different people have changed the same code on different branches, so they can't be automatically *merged*?

Comment: I borked the wording there... I indeed meen pushes being rejected, and with other 'errors' I'm indeed talking about things like merge conflicts. Thus far, those 2 are the only issues the team has encountered and couldn't solve by pulling first

Comment: OK, so before you can try to _recreate_ any of these errors, you need to be clear in your own head what errors you're talking about. If you first understand why each error occurs, causing one deliberately should be easy. At the moment, your question is a bit too vague to help with, because you haven't really said _what_ you're trying to simulate.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't really care about the content of your repository. I.e. it doesn't know that it's Perl scripts, nor does it check the syntax or validity the code.

I also couldn't think of a case where git would reject commits by default. It's not a common or usual thing.

In general I would recommend working with this workflow: https://barro.github.io/2016/02/a-succesful-git-branching-model-considered-harmful/